# Make Executable Binary File From Elf Using GNU objcopy

Tags: linux, file, executable, gnu, objcopy

I'd like to copy an executable ELF file via:

```
$ objcopy -O binary myfile.elf myfile.bin
```

Unfortunately:

```
$ chmod +x myfile.bin
$ ./myfile.bin
```

results in: cannot execute binary file

Is there any way to retain the files executability?

Comment: Why do you ask, and what is the purpose of doing that?

Comment: I tried to answer, but your question does not seem to make any sense, and makes me believe you don't understand some basic concepts (like the role of a kernel, what are syscalls, what is an operating system, etc...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To be executable by the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall, a file usually has to be some [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) file (or some script, or some old `a.out` format). But see also [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc)

Your [objcopy(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objcopy.1.html) command is loosing the essential meta-data in the ELF file. Maybe you want [strip(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strip.1.html)

Recall that [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) is quite a complex and versatile format, it specifies the starting address, the interpreter ([ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) dynamic linker), the several segments of the program etc. All this meta-data is needed by the kernel for `execve(2)` and is lost with `objcopy -O binary` ...

When you use [objcopy -O binary](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html), you are copying only the binary data:

> objcopy can be used to generate a raw binary file by using an output target of `binary' (e.g., use -O binary). When objcopy generates a raw binary file, it will essentially produce a memory dump of the contents of the input object file. All symbols and relocation information will be discarded. The memory dump will start at the load address of the lowest section copied into the output file.

In particular you lose the entry point and the segments list given in the original ELF header. The kernel cannot guess them.

I don't understand why you expect the result of `objcopy -O binary` to be executable by Linux using `execve(2)`. The main purpose of that `objcopy -O binary` command is to make [firmware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware) or kernel-like stand-alone (or freestanding) binaries, and then you need to exactly understand how they should look like (e.g. what is their starting point, how they are loaded and started) and you probably also use some very specific [linker script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html), and of course that binary cannot contain any [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) to the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) (in particular cannot do any kind of input or output the way a plain Linux executable does them).

Read also more about [ABIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), the [x86-64 ABI](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20120918205429/http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), the [Linux Assembly HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/), the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com) book.

You probably should read a good OS textbook like [Operating System: Three Easy Pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

Comment: The link to the `x86-64 ABI` is broken.